# LOOKUP acts weird in Google Sheet

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

**Expected behavior**:

LOOKUP to retrieve value in B column that matches the value in E column like this:
http://prntscr.com/uj4zlg

**Actual Behavior**

It matches randomly and it retrieves I don't know what:
http://prntscr.com/uj4x8x

**Steps to reproduce**

In column F write formula `=LOOKUP(E2,E$2:E$31,B$2:B$31)` then drag it all the way down.

Why is this happening?
Is there a way to debug it?

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, what you're trying to do doesn't make very much sense. Why not just use `=B2` then drag down? Can you clarify why exactly you're trying to look up a cell in the same range you're matching against? It seems you're not truly "looking up" anything.

Comment: @esqew it doesn't make sense because this is a mockup since in the data i need it doesnt work so I am testing. In the other sheet i want to autopopulate Items based on SKU http://prntscr.com/uj573g .

Comment: Try instead `=index(B$2:B$31, match(E2, E$2:E$31,0))` and let me know if it worked.

Comment: @Marios, yes that works too

Answer (score 1):

`LOOKUP` looks through a **sorted** row or column for a key.

The search range needs to be sorted in order to work properly.

**Solutions:**

- use VLOOKUP with temporary created table from columns E and B. Used to VLOOKUP to the left:

`=VLOOKUP(E2, {$E$2:$E$31,$B$2:$B$31}, 2, FALSE)`

`{$E$2:$E$31,$B$2:$B$31}` creates 'in memory' temporary table where column E is now first on index 1, and column B is second on index 2.

- Use combination of INDEX and MATCH:

`=INDEX(B$2:B$31, MATCH(E2, E$2:E$31,0))`

Thanks @Marios for that one